# When, during the life cycle of a Request, does a web.config <location path='The/Path'> tag execute?

Tags: asp.net, request, lifecycle

When, during the life cycle of a Request, does a web.config `<location path='The/Path'>` tag execute?

Answer (score 2):

The web.config is parsed at application start. It will depend on what elements are contained within the location tag as to how it will affect each individual request.

Comment: if the location tag appeared as follows:

<location path="The/Path">
        <system.web>
            <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1500"/>
        </system.web>
    </location>

when would this be parsed/executed?

Answer (score 0):

app settings are already available on the **OnInit()** method. do you need them before OnInit?